# Filtering a MS-Access recordset based on records in another recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two tables (lets call them Parameters 1 and 2) which both have a many-many relationship with a third table (Options). I need to group the third table records into three groups:

1. Those exclusively related to [specific Parameter 1 record],
2. Those exclusively related to [specific Parameter 2 record] and
3. Those related to both [specific Parameter 1 record] and [specific Parameter
   2 record].

I can ignore Option records not related to either of them.

I need to be able to specify which Parameter 1 and 2 records apply in a form (using combo boxes), and have VBA juggle the three lists in the background, updating them as the Option records they contain are "used" elsewhere in the form (with check boxes).

At the risk of asking a *bad question* I'll submit the code I have - even though it's not a code that fails, just the framework for one that isn't even finished enough to debug yet. I simply haven't got the tools to complete it, as I don't know what methods/properties of what things to use to do it, and can't seem to find the answers in my own research thus far. Comments directing me to other resources will be appreciated, even if you don't have an answer that you're sure is best practice.

```
Function SetOptions()
If IsNull(cmbParam1) Or IsNull(cmbParam2) Then
    MsgBox "You must select both an Param1 and a Param2!", vbCritical, "Wait!"
    Exit Function
End If

'Recordsets of allowed Options
Dim Param1Opt, Param2Opt, OverlapOpt

'create recordset of tblOption.Option(s) referenced in qryPr1Opt with Param1 from cmbParam1
Param1Opt = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblPr1Opt.Option FROM tblPr1Opt " &_
"WHERE Param1 = '" & cmbParam1 & "';")
'create recordset of tblOption.Option(s) referenced in qryPr2Opt with Param2 from cmbParam2
Param2Opt = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblPr2Opt.Option FROM tblPr2Opt " &_
"WHERE Param2 = '" & cmbParam2 & "';")
'create recordset of tblOption.Option(s) in qryOptOvrlp with Param2 and Param1 from form
OverlapOpt = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT qryOptOvrlp.Option FROM qryOptOvrlp " &_
"WHERE Param1 = '" & cmbParam1 & "' AND Param2 = '" & cmbParam2 & "';")
OverlapNum = Param1Num + Param2Num

'Steps remaining:
'1. Get Param1Opt and Param2Opt to only include Options not in overlap
For Each oOpt In OverlapOpt
    For Each aOpt In Param1Opt
        If aOpt.Value = oOpt.Value Then
        'filter this record out of Param1Opt
        End If
    Next aOpt
    For Each gOpt In Param2Opt
        If gOpt.Value = oOpt.Value Then
        'filter this record out of Param2Opt
        End If
    Next gOpt
Next oOpt

'2. Get the data in Param1Opt, Param2Opt and OverlapOpt, as well as their
'corresponding Nums to be accessible/editable in other functions/subs
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the values of controls in SQL statements run in the context of Access, using the following syntax:

```
Forms!FormName!ControlName
```

or using square brackets if needed:

```
Forms![Form Name]!ControlName
```

Therefore, instead of opening multiple recordsets, you can express each of your points as a single SQL statement with joined tables. You can then either set the `RowSource` of a combobox or listbox to the statement (if you are only using the statement in one place); or you can save the statement as an Access query, and use the query name as the `RowSource` (if you need the statement in multiple places).

Given the following schema:

[image: Schema diagram of relationships]

and two comboboxes: `cmbParam1` and `cmbParam2` on a form named `Form1`, you can use SQL statements as follows:

---

#### 1. Records from `Options` which match `tblPr1Opt` but have no match in `tblPr2Opt`

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Options.Option
FROM (Options 
INNER JOIN tblPr1Opt ON Options.Option = tblPr1Opt.Option) 
LEFT JOIN tblPr2Opt ON Options.Option = tblPr2Opt.Option
WHERE tblPr2Opt.Option IS NULL
    AND tblPr1Opt.Param1 = Forms!Form1!cmbParam1
```

Or using the query designer (note the arrow head next to `tblPr2Opt`; this indicates a left join):

[image: Options with related tblPr1Opt, but no related tblPr2Opt]

---

#### 2. Records from `Options` which match `tblPr2Opt` but have no match in `tblPr1Opt`:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Options.Option
FROM (Options 
INNER JOIN tblPr2Opt ON Options.Option = tblPr2Opt.Option)
LEFT JOIN tblPr1Opt ON Options.Option = tblPr1Opt.Option
WHERE tblPr1Opt.Option IS NuLL
    AND tblPr2Opt.Param2 = Forms!Form1!cmbParam2;
```

or in the query designer:

[image: Options with related tblPr2Opt, but no related tblPr1Opt]

---

#### 3. Records from `Options` which match on both:

```
SELECT Options.Option
FROM (Options 
INNER JOIN tblPr1Opt ON Options.Option = tblPr1Opt.Option) 
INNER JOIN tblPr2Opt ON Options.Option = tblPr2Opt.Option
WHERE tblPr1Opt.Param1 = Forms!Form1!cmbParam1
    AND tblPr2Opt.Param2 = Forms!Form1!cmbParam2
```

Or in the query designer:

[image: Options with related tblPr1Opt and related tblPr2Opt]

Comment: I finally get how this answer works. Sorry that took so long. Still have questions though - the point was to be able to access the values in these recordsets (queries) in VBA in order to do things automatically on the form. How do you refer to the saved queries in VBA?

Comment: @IsaacReefman No problem. Is there any way I could make this answer clearer? RE: opening a recordset off a saved query, I think the simplest way here would be `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MyQueryName")`.

Comment: @IsaacReefman Thanks for the edit, The main point of my answer is not that you can save the statements as Access saved queries (although you certainly can and should do that if it makes sense), but that you can refer to the value of controls in SQL statements in the Access context; this also means that you don't need VBA to generate the statement, you can set it directly in the properties of the output combobox or listbox.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to go ahead and mark it as accepted because the bit that it doesn't address was the "2." part of my code, and that bit was barely a concept.

Comment: Basically each of the records in `tblOptions` has a checkbox on the form identifying whether it is to be applied to the record in another table that this form is helping to create. I want the checkboxes to become enabled or disabled based on whether they are "allowed" by the above schema, which also includes (not listed here) a number. I'd love if you're interested enough to see what i mean by this, illustrated a little better here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/11832/2 Especially as you could possibly help me finish implementing it... Step 45 of seven million or so...

Comment: @IsaacReefman I think the way to go is to open a new question for this. 1) Describe the table columns and relationships between them using `CREATE TABLE` statements, or using the Access Relationship view; this description must include the new record type the form is being used to create. 2) Describe the data entry form; a screenshot would be very helpful. Note that as your actual database might have other tables / coilumns / forms / controls, you probably should create a new Access database with the simplified schema and form; and use that as a source for your screenshots.

Comment: @IsaacReefman We should probably also delete the comments here which are no longer relevant.